# Android MapView - Show swipe-able detail fragment on map marker click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mapview

Please do you know how to display swipe-able detail fragment on map marker click in MapView like in GoogleMaps? Thank you for yours answers. :-)

[image: GoogleMap with detail fragment]
[image: GoogleMap with detail fragment]
[image: GoogleMap with detail fragment]